# How to set host name in symfony2 application

Tags: symfony, routes, hostname, vhosts

Now I am trying to test host_name based routing in symfony2 application. But every time host name is set to localhost. Is there any way to similate host name as "a.example.com" and "b.example.com". So that I can test host_name based routing in symfony2.

I tried to directly set host name in app.php or app_dev.php. Appears to be not working.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean when you mention "test host_name based routing". Is it about PHPUnit testing or some other way of testing?

Comment: Its not unit testing. Just a browser testing.

Comment: Have you tried to add a.example.com to your /etc/hosts file ?

Comment: Yes I tried with that, and it appears to working. Thank you.